# Django rest framework jwt call own api

Tags: python, django, rest

this is my first Django REST framework page. I have two API calls, one of them can call from the GUI and now I want to call it from another API call. What is the best practice to do this. Do i need call it like an external API call? I prepare a dict, with the post data, but I use django-rest-framework-jwt to authentication, do I need to forward the token and how can I do that? I think there should be a way to call my API view easier, but I can't find it.

```
class Projects(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        data=request.data
        ...
class SyncProjects(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        PostContent={
           'name':newProject["name"],
           'projectParent':''
           ...
        }
```

Comment: Did you ever find what to do here? I am in the same dilemma